# Java equivalent for vim-latex folds

Tags: plugin-vim-latex, filetype-java

Vim-Latex has a feature which folds the tex document into the respective environments e.g. sections,equations. Can I enable somthing similar for Java?

Comment: Where do you want the folds, and what is your current `foldmethod` setting?

Comment: Thanks for the referral to foldmethod. I just needed to do :set foldmethod syntax. This looks like something to learn more about.